# Shared custom element creation performance

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component, custom-element

The Polymer documentation suggests using a custom element for sharing some static data, like configuration. Something like `<app-settings>`.

I'm wondering whether it is optimal from performance point of view. Whenever such non-visual element is used it has to be created nonetheless. Wouldn't it be better to simply share the settings in a global variable or in a form of a (AMD/requirejs) module?

The same goes for purely functional tags like `<iron-ajax>`. If I place many of the inside my custom elements wouldn't it affect performance as opposed to simply using some existing XHR library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** it's not optimal from a performance point of view.

Custom Elements are slowly created (and is even slower with polyfill).

I think a non-visual object gains nothing to be a Custom Element.

You're right, a simple object would do the job better. Don't get polymerized :-)

http://jsperf.com/new-vs-create-element/3

Comment: Hm, in Polymer's case declarative data binding would be a benefit. Do you think it's not enough to justify using custom elements for non-visual tags?

Comment: I prefer not relying on third party Libraries for the architecture / foundations of my application.

Comment: OK I understand. If you prefer declarative notation then use it if it's fast enough. I prefer not relying on third-party libraries for the architecture / model / foundations of my application. Idem concerning potential performance issue. If I can use core Javascript I prefer (in a long-term perspective). Also, I'm not a fan of MVC but I don't like to mix the (declarative html) View with the (javascript object) Model (data structure).